# "Least expected" or "least unexpected"

Tags: meaning-in-context, negation, ambiguity, superlative-degree

When I was talking to my girlfriend, she mentioned an incident where one of her friends surprised her with a gift. She said something like *that least unexpected ...* after which we got into a debate that *least expected* is right rather than *least unexpected*.

I said that *least unexpected* would be more like *expected*. After this, I googled the phrase and to my surprise found that *least unexpected* is used to express something that was not expected in many places. For instance, [this](http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowUserReviews-g30349-d2264227-r141380923-The_Hayloft_Family_Restaurant-Afton_Wyoming.html):

> “A Gem in the least unexpected place”

So I'm a bit confused now. Which one is right?

Comment: Can you include some of the phrases you found where least unexpected is used to mean something that was not expected. It seems like it is being used wrong.

Comment: @Urbycoz I found googling them, ex: "A Gem in the least unexpected "

Comment: Can you post the link, so we can have more context.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. I have taken the liberty of incorporating your Google finding into your question; around here it's regarded as a courtesy to answerers to provide this sort of information in the question, to save them the trouble of looking it up for themselves.

Answer (score 4):

*Least expected* refers to something that is the least likely (or most unlikely) to happen. *Least unexpected* refers to something that is the least unlikely (or most likely) to happen. Using one for the other is simply a mistake.

Answer (score 3):

*Least unexpected* may in some contexts be the phrase called for. These, for instance, from the first page of Google results on “least unexpected”:

> The Least! Unexpected! News! Story . . . !Evah [source](http://supportyourlocalgunfighter.com/2012/06/the-least-unexpected-news-story-evah/)
>
> The least unexpected award of the night – Meryl Streep gets her gong for The Iron Lady. [source](http://wodumedia.com/golden-globes-2012-winners/the-least-unexpected-award-of-the-night-meryl-streep-gets-her-gong-for-the-iron-lady/)

Nobody was surprised that Tom Cruise was divorced and Meryl Streep won the Golden Globe; everybody *expected* these events, so neither story was at all *unexpected*. It is only a modest hyperbole to describe these as *least unexpected*.

On the other hand, this review (also from Google first-page results) clearly has it wrong:

> “A Gem in the least unexpected place” ... We were on our way to Grand Tetons and had a long day of driving. We were both thinking lets just find a local "greasy spoon" and check it out ... [source](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96381/least-expected-or-least-unexpected#96385)

In conversation, or in quick, casual writing, people use the words that occur to them on the spot. *Unlikely* or *unexpected*, get jumbled up with *least likely*, *least expected*, and the result is *least unexpected*. Nobody rewrites, nobody's keeping score, both speakers/writers and hearers/readers understand what is meant, so there's no harm done. Such misuses are not in the least unexpected.